# Action Sheet Within ActionSheet

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiactionsheet

am new to Objective C and iPhone Development. 
 Kindly tell me how can i add an action sheet within action sheet. 
Like when i tap a button an action sheet is opened and then I clicked the first ButtonIndex of action another action sheet appears. 
Kindly mention the complete code. 
Thanks

Comment: The action sheet apears but it buttonIndex are not selected. 
action still take place of that 1st action sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you want to do is dismiss the first UIActionSheet and show another UIActionSheet in it's place. In other words, you don't want to show a UIActionSheet *within* another UIActionSheet -- you want to show a UIActionSheet after a different UIActionSheet has been dismissed.

To find out when an action sheet is being dismissed, you should implement the [UIActionSheetDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIActionSheetDelegate) protocol. For example:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
// first action sheet is dismissed
// show a new action sheet here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UIActionSheet` delegate method:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) { // Add an action sheet for one of these buttons -> maybe here if you want...

     NSLog(@"You clicked the first button...");

     UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Another action sheet"
     delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Button" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destructive" 
     otherButtonTitles:@"Other Button 1", nil];

    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;

    [popupQuery showInView:self.view];

    [popupQuery release];

    } 

    else {

        NSLog(@"Dismissing action sheet");

    }

}
```